# Prevent useState rerendering animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I have set up a realtime firebase that detects user joining my site. When they join, I add them to my useState variable and then display them on the map. I use framer motion to create a simple animation.

The problem is that when a user gets added, removed, or modified that user gets animated, and all the other users get animated again as well. I have tried to use React.memo, with no success. Maybe I am just using it wrong or there is another solution that I can't come up with yet.

```
const [onlineUsers, setOnlineUsers] = useState([]);
```

```
{onlineUsers?.map((user) => (
  <motion.g
        initial={{ scale: 0 }}
        animate={{ rotate: 0, scale: 1 }}
        transition={{
          type: 'spring',
          stiffness: 260,
          damping: 20,
        }}
      >
        <image
          width='12'
          height='12'
          href={UserImage}

        />
      </motion.g>
))}
```

Comment: how about add key property to montion.g

Answer (score 0):

Framer motion detect animate from key attribute, set unique key to each iterated element.

Comment: It didn't help since useState rerenders everything upon a change.
I went with using useRef instead.

I appreciate the answers!

Answer (score 0):

How `useState` and `useMemo` works? Every time an element changes, it will re-render the whole component. As you are storing all users in `onlineUsers`, once you modified `onlineUsers` will re-render your variable (all elements inside your variable). Check [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-list-transitions-forked-nqd2r)